# ORA-1858 Error when using Arabic frontend

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, ora-01858

I have created package on my database and it is working when i run quick pay from English front end ,but it giving error when i run quick pay from ARABIC front end
the error is ORA-1858.

my package is about end of service of the employees.it is calculates Days,Months,years,absence
net days,net months,net years

Comment: Are you applying date formats to any fields? If so you may have a mismatch in date format. If not then are you relying on your default NLS date format? Is this causing you the problem?